# Why the Code After Array.foreach doesn't execute?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get value of a **global variable** (`screenDisplay`) after completing the **for each** portion. 
But it seems whenever the **2nd Part** is put before the **1st Part**, the value that i am supposed to get from `screenDisplay` comes `undefined` and the console throws an **error**.

**error*

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toFixed')
```

**Why does the `screenDisplay`'s value gets affected when part 2 is kept after part 1?**

To find the error directly input values to the screen without using calculator key. ex. (2+3)
[Live Link Here](https://mustakabsarkhan.github.io/Calculator-App/)

```
const screenDisplay = document.getElementById("screen-input-selector");

const result = () => {
  focusInitiate();
  try {

    **//1st Part**

    // * auto multiplication feature

    displaylocalStorageDATA();
    const screenItems = [...screenDisplay.value];
    let screenPosition = screenDisplay.selectionStart;

    screenItems.forEach((item, index) => {
      let indexno = index + 1;

      if (
        screenItems.length != indexno &&
        ![")", "+", "-", "*", "/"].includes(screenItems[index + 1]) &&
        item == ")"
      ) {
        let remainingDataFirstPortion = screenItems.slice(0, index + 1); //selects and stores the rest of the portion of the text after cursor

        let remainingDataLastPortion = screenItems.slice(
          index + 1,
          screenItems.length
        );

        const clearedArray = remainingDataFirstPortion.concat("*");
        const clearedArray1 = clearedArray.concat(remainingDataLastPortion);

        screenDisplay.value = clearedArray1.join("");
        displaylocalStorageSTORE();
        screenDisplay.setSelectionRange(screenPosition, screenPosition);
      }
    });

    //2nd Part

    const inputData = localStorage.getItem("display");

    if (inputData != null) {
      //when inputdata and screendisplay value are same
      if (inputData == screenDisplay.value) {
        //when local storage has some value
        displaylocalStorageREMOVE();
        // screenDisplay.value = eval(localStorage.getItem("display"));
        screenDisplay.value = Function("return " + inputData)().toFixed(4); //using function constructor instead of EVAL function cause EVAL() executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller
        displaylocalStorageSTORE();
      } else {
        //when inputdata and screendisplay value are not same
        displaylocalStorageREMOVE();
        screenDisplay.value = Function(
          "return " + screenDisplay.value
        )().toFixed(4);
        displaylocalStorageSTORE();
      }
    } else {
      //when local storage is empty
      screenDisplay.value = Function("return " + screenDisplay.value)().toFixed(
        4
      );
      displaylocalStorageSTORE();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
};
```

Comment: Probably because it throws an error. Did you look at what you get in your `catch` block?

Comment: *"doesn't execute properly*" is not an adequate problem description. What is the current behaviour, what is the desired behaviour? Tried your live demo. Seems to work fine for me ...

Comment: @CherryDT Updated question's description and it gives this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toFixed')`

Comment: @derpirscher Updated question's description and whenever the 2nd Part is put before the 1st Part, the value that i am supposed to get from screenDisplay(global variable) comes undefined and the console throws an error.

Comment: @Liam No sir it doesn't. My main wish is to make the 2nd part work after the 1st part finishes its job. But currently, it isn't doing that. For that, I am trying to understand what prevents the part 2 from getting the global variable value.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Resolved.**

`displaylocalStorageDATA()` (which reassigns locally saved data to the global variable) of Part 1 was causing the problem. It was redefining the `screenDisplay.value`.

Removing that line has solved the problem.

Thanks, Everyone.